# ASP.NET MVC Paging for a search form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, paging

I've read several different posts on paging w/ in MVC but none describe a scenario where I have something like a search form and then want to display the results of the search criteria (with paging) beneath the form once the user clicks submit.

My problem is that, the paging solution I'm using will create <a href="..."> links that will pass the desired page like so: http://mysite.com/search/2/ and while that's all fine and dandy, I don't have the results of the query being sent to the db in memory or anything so I need to query the DB again.

If the results are handled by the POST controller action for /Search and the first page of the data is rendered as such, how do I get the same results (based on the form criteria specified by the user) when the user clicks to move to page 2?

Some javascript voodoo? Leverage Session State? Make my GET controller action have the same variables expected by the search criteria (but optional), when the GET action is called, instantiate a FormCollection instance, populate it and pass it to the POST action method (there-by satisfying DRY)?

Can someone point me in the right direction for this scenario or provide examples that have been implemented in the past? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method is to have an Action that handles both the post and the get scenarios.

This is my which can be handled by both GET and POST methods:

```
public ViewResult Index([DefaultValue(1)] int page,
                        [DefaultValue(30)] int pageSize,
                        string search,
                        [DefaultValue(0)] int regionId,
                        [DefaultValue(0)] int eventTypeId,
                        DateTime? from,
                        DateTime? to)
{
    var events = EventRepo.GetFilteredEvents(page, pageSize, search, regionId, eventTypeId, from, to);
    var eventFilterForm = EventService.GetEventFilterForm(from, to);

    var eventIndexModel = new EventIndexModel(events, eventFilterForm);

    return View("Index", eventIndexModel);
}
```

The `eventFilterForm` is a presentation model that contains some `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties for my search form.

The `eventIndexModel` is a presentation model that combines the `eventFilterForm` and the results of the search - `events`

The `events` is a special type of `IPagedList`. You can get more information and code for that [here](http://www.squaredroot.com/2009/06/15/return-of-the-pagedlist/) and [here](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/). The first link talks about IPagedList where as the second link has an Advanced Paging scenario which you should need.

The advanced paging has the following method that I use:

```
public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, RouteValueDictionary valuesDictionary)
```

And I use it like so:

```
<%= Html.Pager(Model.Events.PageSize,
               Model.Events.PageNumber,
               Model.Events.TotalItemCount,
               new
               {
                   action = "index",
                   controller = "search",
                   search = ViewData.EvalWithModelState("Search"),
                   regionId = ViewData.EvalWithModelState("RegionId"),
                   eventTypeId = ViewData.EvalWithModelState("EventTypeId"),
                   from = ViewData.EvalDateWithModelState("From"),
                   to = ViewData.EvalDateWithModelState("To")
               }) %>
```

This creates links that look like:

> /event/search?regionId=4&eventTypeId=39&from=2009/09/01&to=2010/08/31&page=3

HTHs,
Charles

Ps. `EvalWithModelState` is below:

PPs. If you are going to put dates into get variables - I would recommend reading [my blog post](http://www.pagedesigners.co.nz/2009/12/asp-net-mvc-datetime-binding-and-culture-unaware-urls/) on it... :-)

```
/// <summary>
/// Will get the specified key from ViewData. It will first look in ModelState
/// and if it's not found in there, it'll call ViewData.Eval(string key)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewData">ViewDataDictionary object</param>
/// <param name="key">Key to search the dictionary</param>
/// <returns>Value in ModelState if it finds one or calls ViewData.Eval()</returns>
public static string EvalWithModelState(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, string key)
{
    if (viewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(key))
        return viewData.ModelState[key].Value.AttemptedValue;

    return (viewData.Eval(key) != null) ? viewData.Eval(key).ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the Search parameter part of your View Model:

```
public SearchViewModel
{
    string SearchParameters { get; set; }
    List<SearchObjects> SearchResults { get;set; }
}
```

Then just set the Search Textbox equal to SearchParameters.

You cannot "store" the search query unless you bring back ALL results and then store those in the page somehow.  That is horribly inefficient.  The web is stateless, so you will have to go back to the database and re-query for more results.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are saying; you could change the form to use buttons and post the page back everytime.  Or, you could pass all the criteria in the URL for the paging as querystring variables.  Or you could use JQuery to do the post (it has a $.post method that can be invoked from a link click or other click (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This problem goes away if you include the search text, as well as the current results page, in your querystring instead of POSTing the search text.  As an added benefit, your users can then bookmark their search results.

To do this your search button just needs to build the GET request URL using the current value of the search box.  This can be done either in javascript or by using GET as your search form's method attribute, e.g. `<form method="get" action="/search">`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend cacheing your search results and giving them an ID. Then for each paging link, you can reference the search ID as a parameter (on each search page link) and in your action, pull it from cache, then query over it.

Using this method, you don't need to worry about anything other than the first `POST` submit of the search form.

[Refer to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663616/paging-search-results-with-asp-net-mvc/1664269#1664269) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and [here's what I did](http://www.unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2011/03/30/15977.aspx).

1. Download PagedList from Nuget
2. Change your form to do a GET and create a ViewModel type similiar to this (if you love AdventureWorks and Model Binding as much as I do):

`

```
using PagedList;
namespace SearchFormResultPagingExample.Models {

  public class SearchViewModel {
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Contact> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
  }
}
```

`

3.Use the ViewModel as the parameter to your controller's action method

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SearchFormResultPagingExample.Models;
using PagedList; //NOTE: use Nuget to reference PagedList

namespace SearchFormResultPagingExample.Controllers {
    public class SearchController : Controller {
        const int RecordsPerPage = 25;

        public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchButton) || model.Page.HasValue) {
                var entities = new AdventureWorksEntities();
                var results = entities.Contacts.Where(c => c.LastName.StartsWith(model.LastName) && c.EmailAddress.StartsWith(model.EmailAddress))
                    .OrderBy(o => o.LastName);

                var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 0;
                model.SearchResults = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, 25);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the pager on in your View:

```
@model SearchFormResultPagingExample.Models.SearchViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Search</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input name="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@if (Model.SearchResults != null && Model.SearchResults.Count > 0) {
    foreach (var result in Model.SearchResults) {
            <hr />
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="*">
                        <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size:large;">@result.LastName, @result.FirstName</div>
                        @result.Title<br />
                        @result.Phone<br />
                        @result.EmailAddress
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    }
        <hr />

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults,
            page => Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary() {
               { "Page", page }, 
               { "EmailAddress", Model.EmailAddress },
               { "LastName", Model.LastName }
            }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
}
```

MVC will coerce the querystring to and from your ViewModel type parameter. It's very slick!